# join and group by in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have two tables that I was going to join, but I understand it's more efficient to use `CREATE VIEW`. This is what I have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view0_joinedTablesGrouped 
AS
Select table1.*,table2.*
FROM table1
inner join table2 on table1.col = 
table2.matchingcol
group by table2.matchingcol;
```

which causes the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "table1.col" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be 
used in an aggregate function
LINE 3: Select table.*,table2.*
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the view creation. It is necessary to aggregate the other columns. You did not explain why are you grouping.

Comment: The data geographic area in format country, district,area etc. I want to create views which summarise by country,district area etc.

Comment: A view isn't more or less efficient. It is just a way to hide a potentially complex query and have its results look like a table. Each time the view is accessed, the query is re-run. It's sort of like an alias. Also, we'll need to know more about the structure of your tables and the result you want in order to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Group By** cannot do what you are trying to do.

Consider a simple table:

```
Name Age
-------
Ann  10
Bill 10
Chris 11
```

If you try to group by age with:

```
Select * from Table group by Age
```

What, exactly, do you expect to appear in the `Name` column for `Age=10`? Ann, or Bill or both or neither or ....? There *is* no good answer.

So, when you `group by`, every column in the output has to be an `aggregate` – that means a function of *every* row in the group.

So these are valid:

```
Select Age, Count(*) from Table group by Age
Select Age, Max( Length(Name)) from Table group by Age
Select Age, Max(Name) from Table group by Age
```

But this is impossible to do, and isn't valid:

```
Select Age,Name from Table group by Age
```

So your `select *` is the problem -- you can't just select column values because when you `group by` there's a whole *group* of column values for every output row, and you can't stuff all those values into one column of one row.

As for using a view, @systemjack's comment is correct.